# Hanami: asset URL helper in stylesheets

Tags: sass, hanami

I am using Hanami 1.3.5 and `sassc` 2.4.0.

I want to use the an image url helper inside of an Hanami stylesheet (like it's possible in Rails):

```
body
  background-image: image-url('zipper.svg')
```

but this the `image-url` doesn't get evaluated.

Also naively using Hanami's built in `asset_path` helper does not work:

```
body
  background-image: url(#{asset_path('zipper.svg')})
```

So is it even possible?